Dynamically change colours with CSS so background and text colour aren't clashing
I'm facing the problem that users can change background colours for HTML components which sometimes conflict with text colours they can't change (or more generally, background and text colour are visually too similar). As a result, the text may become invisible (or difficult to see) if those colours are visually close enough.
See below where's there's a triangle (=text)...

...which only becomes more visible on hover.

(the user could also have also opted for a grey background which would have made this even worse)
I've tried to tinker with filters (e.g. filter: brightness(50%) contrast(150%); or filter: saturate(0) grayscale(1) brightness(.7) contrast(1000%) invert(1) as suggested here), but that's sensitive to the selected colours (i.e. may not work in all cases of background and text colour combinations). Is there a way (in CSS, without JS as shown here) that would change the text colour slightly (ideally, the "type of colour" itself is somewhat maintained), so that text on conflicting (too close) background and text colours becomes visible?
I realise that this question is asking for 2 things (1. detecting the conflict and 2. resolving the conflict by applying some sort of filter (or others)). If some suggestions are made for how to resolve the conflicting colours (2.), I'd already be happy.
Trying mix-blend-mode: difference
Without mix-blend-mode: difference;

With mix-blend-mode: difference;


mix-blend-mode of difference is one option

Thanks @ZachJensz, but mix-blend-mode: difference makes it worse in some circumstances (see above). It seems that the other mix-blend-mode options aren't of much use for this instance either.

Check out this article

This article demonstrates a CSS method for switching the (text) color between black and white based on the (perceived) luminance of the background color. So it’s not exactly what you’re asking for, but it’s close.
A simpler alternative you could consider is using a contrasting text-shadow to improve readability when the text and background colours are similar.


:root {
  --clr-white-80: rgb(255 255 255 / 0.8);
}

body {
  background: lightsalmon;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

p {
  color: peru;
  margin: 0;
}

.p2 {
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px var(--clr-white-80);
}

.p3 {
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px var(--clr-white-80);
}

.p4 {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 var(--clr-white-80);
}
<p class="p1">Is this readable?</p>
<p class="p2">What about now?</p>
<p class="p3">Or with a larger spread</p>
<p class="p4">Or with an offset</p>




Interesting article, in particular the luma-corrected calculations. I'll need to go through it more thoroughly to see whether it can be used. The problem I see is that I don't want the set colour to be changed, unless it needs to be changed (defaulting to white/black to change is ok). Also, the colour is already set (style -> color: ...) - how would I get this into variables for this transformation?

The text shadow is also a nice idea, but it looks a bit blurry and if I reduce the blurriness, it looks like a double-up of the text (I guess that's how a "text-shadow" is supposed to look like ;-)).

I added a third example with zero blur but with an offset.

The need for CSS to address this problem has been recognised, and a CSS function contrast-color() has been drafted to help. At this stage, experimental support for this function is available only in Safari TP.
Note that the spec says the function is to be called contrast-color(), but what Safari TP has currently implemented is color-contrast().

Thanks for sharing this interesting development in CSS spec.
